# DateTime Column type for import

Tags: import, date-time

I am looking at this http://spfileupload.codeplex.com/ to import files/folders with metadata. but it seems that DateTime is not supported. What's your input on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an odd question, as you know the answer.

You're grabbing some freeware off codeplex and it is what it is.  For whatever reason, the author chose not to support date/time values in his script.  You could take this sample script and add that support or you can look at other free/for fee options.